# Securing database entry access - webmatrix

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have a page on my site where a user can update property informtation in a database. Currently, the property details are pulled using a query string like this:

http://somedomain.com/account/PropertyRooms.cshtml?propertyid=18

The problem i have, is that i only want users to be able to update their own property, not others. Currently, any user can manually change the querystring and edit another property.

I am trying to lock this down using a variation of the "AutheticatedUser" value, and matching that to the "ownerID" column in the table. If they don't match, i want to redirect to an error or a login page? Here's my current config, which partly works.

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

var CurrentUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; 

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var rPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];

var Propertyinfo = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0 AND OwnerID=@1";
var qPropertyinfo = db.QuerySingle(Propertyinfo, rPropertyId, CurrentUser);
}

<h2>Property Information</h2>
   <form method="post" action="">
      <fieldset>
         <label>Property ID</label>
         <input class="input-mini" id="disabledInput" type="text" value="@qPropertyinfo.PropertyID" placeholder="Disabled input here..." disabled>
      </fieldset>
   </form>
```

i need to know if this is the best way to secure my site, or should i run a seperate SQL query to check first? If i'm doing it right, what code do i need to add if the page fails because the OwnerID and PropertyID don't match up?

Thanks, Gavin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way I would approach it. You should generally aim to minimise calls to a database as much as is practical. In other words, if you can solve the problem with one call, you should not be looking for alternative solutions that require more.

If no rows match both the user id and propertyid, the qPropertyInfo variable will be null, so you can test for that:

```
@if(qPropertyInfo != null){
    //let them update their details
}
else{
    //display a no results found message
}
```

You can read more about how to check if a query returns data in ASP.NET Web Pages in my article on the subject: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/214/How-To-Check-If-A-Query-Returns-Data-In-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Comment: And do you mean do this in the code block, or in the body of the page?

Comment: It depends on the design of your app. I wrote that snippet on the assumption that you would put it in the body of the page, but you could put it in a code block and redirect to another page if no matching property is found. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: ok, let me try both scenarios and i'll let you know if i run into any problems. but i've read your article and that makes sense, so should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that worked a treat. Just one more quick question, under the "else" statement, would i be best using a response.redirect command to redirect the user back to the login page?

Comment: Again, that depends on the experience you want to provide to your user. If the only way that you could get a wrong combination is by tampering with the url, then I think an unceremonious redirect with no explanation is appropriate - bit like a ruler across the knuckles...